# Configure next.js to with Babel not to transform async functions

Tags: async-await, electron, babeljs, next.js

With the default config, Next is directing Babel to use generators for my async functions on the client-side. This is making debugging more challenging that it seems like it should be. How do I disable this behavior?

I'm using an Electron app, so I really want the minimal amount of transformation to match the Chromium runtime.

Here's my current `"babel"` key contents in my `package.json`:

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "next/babel",
        {
          "preset-env": {
            "targets": {
              "chromium": 73,
              "node": 11
            }
          },
          "transform-runtime": {
            "regenerator": false
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

The result here is that regenerator isn't included, but it crashes within Webpack-generated code. If I remove the disabling of `regenerator`, I can see that the assets are still transpiling `async` functions to generators, anyway.

[image]

Comment: Try adding `node: 10` to `targets`

Comment: @evgenifotia That did not work :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that `chromium` is a valid target per [browsers list](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers) documentation. Try `"chrome": "73"` as a target. Note that the value for a given target should be a string type, not a number.

If there is a plugin that you don't want to include then the `exclude` key should let you [blacklist a plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#exclude) that would otherwise be used based on the target environments that you provided. `"exclude": ["@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator"]`.

**Question Asker's note**

This solved my problem. I achieved the desired result with:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "next/babel",
      {
        "preset-env": {
          "targets": {
            "chrome": "73",
            "node": "11"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: One of those ideas worked! When I find the minimal config, I'll drop it in your answer and accept.

Comment: The debugger lets me step through `await`s as expected!

Comment: Embarrassingly, `"chrome": "73"` was all it took. But in my defense, it's kind of alchemy until you figure out the right incantation. Otherwise it just silently doesn't do what you think it's supposed to do.

Comment: Am I allowed to say "I love you" on Stack Overflow? Been looking to solve this for years!

Comment: How to keep all of the features introduced by es6+ intact?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for next.js and Webpack 5 sadly :/