# Disable es5 transpilation while developing in nextjs

Tags: next.js

Is there a way to disable transpilation of es5 code (such as async functions) while in `next dev`?

Setting the babel preset-env does not work, and [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55473659/configure-next-js-to-with-babel-not-to-transform-async-functions) no longer works either.

Setting the browserlist target within package.json still transpiles the code as well

Comment: Unfortunately, with all the big changes with Next as of late (like the move to swc and what not), most old solutions won't be applicable still. From what I can tell, there's really not a great way to do this, or at least, Vercel hasn't given us an obvious way. This may honestly be worth opening an issue on github.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm thinking as well. Opened this up https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/37595 - thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Jan 2023 I found a few flags that help get you most of the way there.

```js
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config, { dev }) => {
    if (dev && Array.isArray(config.target) && config.target.includes('web')) {
      config.optimization.minimize = false;
      delete config.optimization.minimizer;
      config.target = ["web", "es2020"];
    }
    return config;
  }
};

if (!isProd) {
  nextConfig.experimental = {
    legacyBrowsers: false,
  };
}

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

This will disable legacy browser support and use your browser list for swc, and then also changes the targets for webpack. Doesn't completely remove transpilation but it's way better than the default

Also, nextjs now supports browserslist in your package.json - [source](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/supported-browsers-features)

Adding the following key to your package.json will enable most features by default:

```
{
  "browserslist": [
    "chrome 109"
  ]
}
```